# reading cause for start-up of atmega16

Tags: c, atmega16

Here is my code for reading the MCUCSR register
and making alarms from the 3 bits PORF, EXTRF, WDRF.
I expected this to be trivial, but it does not work.

Any idea?

```
static uint8_t mcucsr __attribute__ ((section (".noinit")));

static volatile union
{
  struct
  {
    uint32_t watchdog:1;
    uint32_t powerfail:1;
    uint32_t reset:1;
    uint32_t startup:1;
  } b;
  uint32_t w;
} __attribute__ ((packed)) alarms;


static void wdinit ()
{
  mcucsr = MCUCSR;
  MCUCSR &= ~(1 << PORF);
  MCUCSR &= ~(1 << EXTRF);
  MCUCSR &= ~(1 << WDRF);
} __attribute__((naked)) __attribute__ ((section (".init3")))


int main ()
{
  alarms.b.startup = true;
  alarms.b.powerfail |= !!(mcucsr & (1 << PORF));
  alarms.b.reset     |= !!(mcucsr & (1 << EXTRF));
  alarms.b.watchdog  |= !!(mcucsr & (1 << WDRF));
  mcucsr = 0;
  ...
```

Comment: What does not work? What do you expect to happen? How are you using the alarms?

Comment: Please have a look at alarm startup, which I just added for completeness.
Whenever I force a restart by triggering a watchdog I always see
the startup alarm, but not the watchdog alarm.
It looks like wdinit() is either never called or does not do what it should.

Comment: Thanks - but what exactly is it supposed to do?

Comment: I am recording a number of alarm conditions in my atmega16. Those are periodically polled by a supervisory system and stored in an error log.

Comment: @userXXX And isn't the polling working in this case? Doesn't the log ever appear?

Comment: alarms.b.watchdog never becomes 1, even if I force a watchdog.
Everything else works.